# To destroy card when inactive and instantiate when active in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, cardlayout

> **Goal** : To improve performance of the app and reduce the loading time.When card is active I am instantiating it and its DOM is created, as **deferredRender:true**.Now I want to destroy the card as it gets inactive so as to reduce DOM.But I am somewhat facing some issue during removal and again instantiation of the card.

Here is the simple fiddle , i have created based on my layout structure i am following:
[Card Layout Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6e2)

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913375/extjs-best-way-to-destroy-card-when-hidden-instantiate-when-shown),but failed to understand the implemetation.

> According to the posted fiddle,
>   1. As defferedRender:true, second card is not rendered.Fine.
>
> 2 .As soon as switch to card2,card1 should be destroyed and its DOM should be cleared,which is not happening.

Please help me out resolve this.If I am going wrong somewhere,help me by pointing to right direction.Thnks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that this approach is going to improve the performance. First of all, the most expensive operation in current browsers is the DOM manipulation. Destroy can mean to remove many, many elements if your card is complex, re-create means to insert many, many elements.

Then, if you really want only the active card to be present in the DOM then you don't need card layout because you have only one card and card layout is designed for more cards, one visible at a time. Also, it should be faster to hide the active card and show the inactive than to destroy and re-create.

If you still want to take destroy/create route, use `fit` layout. It is simpler, can have only one item and it can be a tad faster than card if you destroy/create.

Comment: Actually I needed an advice and I agree with you @Saki.Thnks for the reply.I am extensively using card layout in my application.Only my concern was initial load time which I have solved by using deferredRender:true. But if the size of allclasses.js increase in future, will it affect the performance as DOM size will also increase?

Comment: Size of all-classes.js is not a problem in real life as with properly configured http server it is cached so it can delay the app startup only the first time. Bottleneck is nowadays the DOM manipulation: too many grid rows, too many dataview items, complex nesting, too big trees, etc.

Comment: ,please help me point in correct direction.You mentioned to use 'fit' layout and destroy and create accordingly.Can you please provide some approach to achieve that with minimal code change.I have  posted a fiddle accordingly in the question.Thanks

Comment: Well, I do **not** recommend destroy/re-create approach. I recommend standard card layout without extras.

Comment: As application gets bigger,would it be feasible to have all the cards which are not active to be in the DOM after they get rendered once.Thnks again for you advice.